# jest unit test and retry-axios node.js

Tags: typescript, jestjs, retry-axios

I have been trying to use the retry-axios library and assert the number of times in a "get" has been called without any luck. Here is my setup:

axios.config.ts

```
import axios, { AxiosInstance } from 'axios';
import * as rax from 'retry-axios';

export const axiosClient: AxiosInstance = axios.create({
  raxConfig: {
    retry: 3,
    onRetryAttempt: (err: any) => {
      const cfg = rax.getConfig(err);
      console.error(`Retry attempt #${cfg?.currentRetryAttempt}`);
    }
  },
});

rax.attach(axiosClient);
```

api.service.ts

```
import { axiosClient } from 'axios.config';

export class ApiService
{
 callApi = async (endPoint): Promise<any> => {   
    const response: AxiosResponse<any> = await axiosClient.get(endPoint);
    return response.data;
};
```

api.service.spec.ts

```
import { ApiService } from 'api.service';

    it('SHOULD call the end point successfully GIVEN THAT the first attempt fails and the second attempt succeeds.', async () => {
      const service = new ApiService();
      const apiResponse = { data: { content: [] } };
      jest.spyOn(axiosClient, 'get').mockRejectedValueOnce(() => { throw 500 });
      jest.spyOn(axiosClient, 'get').mockResolvedValueOnce(apiResponse);
      try {
        await service.callApi("endpoint");
      }
      catch (e) {
        expect(axiosClient.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
      }
    });
```

Whatever I have tried, the assertions about the number of  "get" calls is always 1.

Here are a few other things I tried throwing an error on mocking the rejection on the first attempt:

```
jest.spyOn(axiosClient, 'get').mockImplementationOnce(async () => { throw 500; });
jest.spyOn(axiosClient, 'get').mockImplementationOnce(async () => { throw new Error(500) ;});
jest.spyOn(axiosClient, 'get').mockRejectedValueOnce(async () => { throw new Error(500); });
jest.spyOn(axiosClient, 'get').mockRejectedValueOnce(() => { return {statusCode: 500}; });
```

Thank you. Please let me know if you need anymore details.

Answer (score 2):

I know that the question is old, but I just spent 3 hours on trying to solve the same problem. The solution would be using `import MockAdapter from "axios-mock-adapter"`:

```
it("Should retry", async () => {
    const mock = new MockAdapter(axios)
    mock.onGet().replyOnce(500, {})
    mock.onGet().replyOnce(200, validResponse)
    callTheApiAndCheckResponse()
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for updating it. I am sure it will help someone. I have since moved off axios and using 'got' instead. It has made my life much easier using the built-in hooks.